# Linting only newly added files

Tags: eslint, lint, stylelint, husky, lint-staged

I'm using lint-staged along with husky to run linters against all the staged files before commit. But my codebase is old; so don't want to run linters against existing (modified) files for now. Is there a way to run linters only against newly created (added) files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to run lint-staged only on new files (the ones that were untracked by git before)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54921803/is-there-a-way-to-run-lint-staged-only-on-new-files-the-ones-that-were-untracke)